# Is there a way to disable premature data fetch in TabBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, tabbar

We have a page with 6-7 tabs.
Whenever we switch the tab the respective data is fetched.
Now the problem is, if the user slightly touches the tab so that the tab doesn't switch completely and comes back, the data from the next tab is fetched in the current tab.

I've tried changing physics of tabbarview.

Is there a way to make sure the data is only fetched when the tab is switched completely?

This is the code,

in my ordersController,

```
late TabController tabController;
tabController = TabController(length: 7, vsync: this);
```

In my ordersScreen,

```
TabBar(
            controller: orderController.tabController,
            onTap: (index) {
              searchController.searchText.value.clear();
            },
            isScrollable: true,
            labelPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.w),
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            labelColor: Constants.TextBlack,
            unselectedLabelColor: Constants.TextBlack,
            indicatorWeight: 3.h,
            indicatorColor: Constants.BackgroundBlue,
            labelStyle: ThemeStyles.NormalBold,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text('All', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Unfulfilled', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Fulfilled', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Partially Refunded', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Refunded', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Hold', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text('Dispute', style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 4.h),
        Expanded(
          child:
          TabBarView(
            controller: orderController.tabController,
            children: const [
              AllOrdersView(),
              AllOrdersView(status: 0),
              AllOrdersView(status: 1),
              AllOrdersView(status: 4),
              AllOrdersView(status: 3),
              AllOrdersView(status: 9),
              AllOrdersView(status: 10),
            ],
          ),
```

In the AllOrderView(),

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class AllOrdersView extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? status;
  const AllOrdersView({Key? key, this.status}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<AllOrdersView> createState() => _AllOrdersViewState();
}

class _AllOrdersViewState extends State<AllOrdersView> with TickerProviderStateMixin
{
  bool isLoadingFirst = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  int page = 1;
  int totalPages = 0;
  RefreshController paginateController = RefreshController();
  AllOrdersModel? orderModel = AllOrdersModel();
  List<OrderDatum> ordersList = [];
  final controller = Get.find<OrderController>();

  Future<void> fetchOrders() async {
    widget.status != null ? await controller.fetchOrdersList(isFirst: true, status: widget.status) : await controller.fetchAllOrdersList(isFirst: true);
  }

  late AnimationController animationController;
  late AnimationController animationController2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    animationController2 = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      fetchOrders();
    });
  }

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (mounted) {
      super.setState(fn);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    animationController2.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
      SizedBox(height: 8.h),
      widget.status != null
          ? Obx(() => controller.firstLoading.value == true
              ? Expanded(child: AlertWidgets.IULoading(animationController1: animationController, animationController2: animationController2))
              : controller.allOrdersList.value.isEmpty
                  ? SizedBox(
                      height: 50.h,
                      width: Get.width,
                      child: Center(child: Text("No orders found", style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold)),
                    )
                  : Expanded(
                      child: ExcludeSemantics(
                        child: SmartRefresher(
                          controller: paginateController,
                          enablePullUp: true,
                          // enablePullDown: true,
                          enablePullDown: false,
                          onRefresh: () async {
                            controller.searchOrder.value = "";
                            if (totalPages >= page) {
                              await controller.fetchOrdersList(isFirst: true, status: widget.status);
                              if (controller.loading.value == false) {
                                paginateController.loadComplete();
                              } else {
                                paginateController.loadFailed();
                              }
                            } else {
                              paginateController.loadNoData();
                            }
                          },
                          onLoading: () async {
                            if (totalPages >= page) {
                              await controller.fetchOrdersList(isFirst: false, status: widget.status);
                              if (controller.loading.value == false) {
                                paginateController.loadComplete();
                              } else {
                                paginateController.loadFailed();
                              }
                            } else {
                              paginateController.loadNoData();
                            }
                          },
                          child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                              itemCount: controller.allOrdersList.value.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                var item = controller.allOrdersList.value[index];
                                return OrderCard(
                                  orderDatum: item,
                                  status: widget.status,
                                );
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
          : Obx(
              () => controller.firstLoading.isTrue
                  ? Expanded(child: AlertWidgets.IULoading(animationController1: animationController, animationController2: animationController2))
                  : controller.allOrdersList.isEmpty
                      ? SizedBox(
                          height: 50.h,
                          width: Get.width,
                          child: Center(child: Text("No orders found", style: ThemeStyles.NormalBold)),
                        )
                      : Expanded(
                          child: ExcludeSemantics(
                            child: SmartRefresher(
                              controller: paginateController,
                              enablePullUp: true,
                              enablePullDown: true,
                              onRefresh: () async {
                                controller.searchOrder.value = "";
                                await controller.fetchAllOrdersList(isFirst: true);
                                if (controller.firstLoading.value == false) {
                                  paginateController.loadComplete();
                                } else {
                                  paginateController.loadFailed();
                                }
                              },
                              onLoading: () async {
                                if (controller.totalPages.value >= controller.page.value) {
                                  await controller.fetchAllOrdersList(isFirst: false);
                                  if (controller.loading.value == false) {
                                    paginateController.loadComplete();
                                  } else {
                                    paginateController.loadFailed();
                                  }
                                } else {
                                  paginateController.loadNoData();
                                }
                              },
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                  itemCount: controller.allOrdersList.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    var item = controller.allOrdersList[index];
                                    return OrderCard(
                                      orderDatum: item,
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
            ),
    ]);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: can you add your code to the quesstion